# customize the shopping cart page without affecting the original

Tags: php, magento, layout, overriding

I am developing a new custom module in magento. I need to customize the shopping cart page without affecting the original cart.phtml. My module name is Stallioni. I have placed the cart.phtml inside frontend/default/default/template/stallioni/checkout/cart.phtml .How can i use this cart.phtml in my new module instead of the original . I know we should change something in checkout.XML or stallioni/layout/stallioni.xml file. But no idea since i am new.I googled out a day but couldn't find.
http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-overriding-template-file-from-custom-module/ this link tells something but it didn't worked for me.I need your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your layout.xml is working add this code in your layout

```
`<checkout_cart_index> 
   <reference name="content">
        <reference name="checkout.cart">
            <action method="setTemplate">               
               <template>default/default/template/stallioni/checkout/cart.phtml</template>
             </action>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>`
```

It should work :)